# What is the difference between Text.Split and Text.SplitAny?

Tags: powerquery, m

The difference between Text.Split and Text.SplitAny is not clear to me. They both seem to use the same syntax and do the same thing. Would someone please explain the difference(s) between them to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Text.Split splits a text at the supplied delimiter (which can contain multiple characters), while Text.SplitAny splits the text at each individual character in the supplied Delimiter.

E.g. Text.Split("MarcelBeug","ce") returns

Mar

lBeug

While Text.SplitAny("MarcelBeug","ce") returns

Mar

lB

ug

Comment: The documentation on [Text.SplitAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260524.aspx) is unfinished. But, like Text.Split, "If two delimiter values are adjacent, or appear at the beginning or end of the text value, the corresponding element in the returned list is an empty text value." So, there would be an empty text value between Mar and lB.